# Get length of json array in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

You know about the new JSON_ support in SQL Server 2016 so
let's say I have this data in a row

```
{
  "BaseBoarding": 1,
  "PriceLineStrategy": "PerPersonPerNight",
  "Currency": "EUR",
  "BasePriceLineList": [
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 1,
      "PeriodId": 1,
      "Price": 10.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 1,
      "PeriodId": 2,
      "Price": 100.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 1,
      "PeriodId": 3,
      "Price": 190.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 2,
      "PeriodId": 1,
      "Price": 280.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 2,
      "PeriodId": 2,
      "Price": 310.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 2,
      "PeriodId": 3,
      "Price": 340.0
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get the number of items of "BasePriceLineList" in the most performant way, preferably using the built-in JSON support?

Need to write something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRLEN(JsonDataCol, '$.BasePriceline') FROM MyTable
WHERE Id = 1
```

and get 6 as the result.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using a table instead of a variable:

```
SELECT count(priceLineLists.RoomTypeId)
FROM Mytable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (JsonDataCol, N'$.BasePriceLineList')
  WITH (
    RoomTypeId int)
      AS priceLineLists
```

Comment: I will mark this as the correct answer because it can be used on multiple rows at once.

Answer (score 28):

The hypothetical SQL statement:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRLEN(JsonDataCol, '$.BasePriceline') FROM MyTable
```

Can be done by the actual statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENJSON(JsonDataCol, '$.BasePriceline')) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 12):

You can convert it to a data set and then count the rows:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{
  "BaseBoarding": 1,
  "PriceLineStrategy": "PerPersonPerNight",
  "Currency": "EUR",
  "BasePriceLineList": [
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 1,
      "PeriodId": 1,
      "Price": 10.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 1,
      "PeriodId": 2,
      "Price": 100.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 1,
      "PeriodId": 3,
      "Price": 190.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 2,
      "PeriodId": 1,
      "Price": 280.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 2,
      "PeriodId": 2,
      "Price": 310.0
    },
    {
      "RoomTypeId": 2,
      "PeriodId": 3,
      "Price": 340.0
    }
  ]
}'

select COUNT(*) 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'$.BasePriceLineList')
WITH (RoomTypeID varchar(100) '$.RoomTypeId')
```

Answer (score 6):

This basic need came up for me a few times when doing some ad-hoc data review. So I went ahead and created a tiny scalar function to do this pretty generically. Few assumptions built in, you might need to use an `isnull` and/or use `json_value` to pull out a nested array you are trying to examine. Also, I really don't know what the performance impact of this would be at any scale, I've only needed to do this on a few dozen records at a time. Just thought I'd share in case anyone else lands here looking for a fairly generic way of doing this.

NOTE: Used a couple hacky "tricks" in this such as making sure the function throws an error on an invalid JSON array even though `throw` isn't allowed inside a function. The extra divide by zero is in case anyone has really lax implicit conversion settings and just a pattern I use in other places where a string return would have been valid.

```
create function array_length (@array nvarchar(max))
returns int as begin
  if (@array is null or isjson(@array) != 1
      or left(@array, 1) + right(@array, 1) <> '[]')
    return 'Invalid JSON array provided to array_length' + (1/0)
  return (select count(*) from openjson(@array))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of digging around and my conclusion is to use this. Remove count if you want to see the queried elements as they were found.  Working with SQL Server 2019

```
SELECT 
COUNT(JSON_QUERY(JsonObject, '$.[0].Region')) AS RegionCount
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This approach is unreliable. The following returns 1, instead of the expected 0: `select count(json_query('[]', 'strict $'))`.